# Convert DAO to ADO

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am trying to create a function that will check all the check boxes in a form with a
datasheet subform.
Since we moved to Office 2013 this code stopped working and it seems that moving to ADO is the only way.

```
Private Sub Toggle_Click()
    Dim sfrm
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    sfrm = Me.Subform
    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
    'Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    'Set rs = Me.Subform.Form.RecordsetClone
  rs.Open Me.Recordset
    If (theTop = 0) Then
    Else
        Me.Subform.Form.AllowAdditions = False
        Dim i As Integer
        If (theHeight = 0) Then
            If (sfrm![Ready?] = -1) Then
                sfrm![Ready?] = 0
                sfrm![Timestamp] = Null
            Else
                sfrm![Ready?] = -1
                sfrm![Timestamp] = Date
            End If
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            For i = theTop To rs.RecordCount
                'If (i = 1) Then
                'Else

                'End If
                'rs.MoveLast
             'Do While Not rs.BOF
                If (sfrm![Ready?] = -1) Then
                    sfrm![Ready?] = 0
                    sfrm![Timestamp] = Null
                Else
                    sfrm![Ready?] = -1
                    sfrm![Timestamp] = Date
                End If

                 'Me.Subform.Form.Recordset.MoveNext
                 rs.MoveNext
                 'Debug.Print sfrm![Routing Number]
               'Loop
            Next
        End If
        Me.Subform.Form.AllowAdditions = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens with that code?  If it throws an error, please tell us the full error message and indicate which line triggers it.  Otherwise, help us understand what the code does and what you need it to do differently.

Answer (score 1):

> it seems that moving to ADO is the only way

With Access 2013, DAO remains the preferred way to interact with Access database objects from within the Access application itself. In my opinion it would be wise for you to investigate *why* the previous DAO code is failing (and how you might fix it) before embarking on a wholesale conversion of DAO code to ADO.

I just did a test in Access 2013. With [ParentTable}

[image: ParentTable.png]

[ChildTable]

[image: ChildTable.png]

and a form like this

[image]

I could toggle the [Selected?] status of the current subform records with the following code:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdToggleChildren_Click()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = Me.ChildSubform.Form.Recordset
    If Not (rst.BOF And rst.EOF) Then
        rst.MoveFirst
        Do Until rst.EOF
            rst.Edit
            rst![Selected?] = Not rst![Selected?]
            rst.Update
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gord, Thanks for the advice and tip. :)